# Cannot install therubyracer, gcc version update on OSX Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, gcc, osx-leopard, therubyracer

So after making my first scaffold using Rails, I tried to access some of the pages it created, and got the following error:

```
     ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index

     Showing /Users/Alice/Desktop/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

     dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022

     (in /Users/Alice/Desktop/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee)
     Extracted source (around line #6):

     3: <head>
     4:   <title>SampleApp</title>
     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     8: </head>
     9: <body></code>
```

I looked up this error and I concluded that I needed to install therubyracer gem.  I tried to do this via gem install therubyracer.

Then I got the error:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/Alice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    creating Makefile
    Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
    It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
    Using compiler: g++
    File "./gyp-mac-tool", line 167
    fd = os.open(lockfile, os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_CREAT, 0o666)
                                                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I run gcc -version, and I see that my version is i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1
I've tried to update my gcc using MacPorts, and I can't seem to make it work at all...

I'm running OSX Leopard, which I'm guessing is the cause of all my grief.
What do I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try another one. https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
Look at the list, these basically all do the same thing. I'm sure you'll find one that works.